# Contar cantidad MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Cuento con 3 tablas y tengo la duda de como obtener una cantidad.

Clientes(cuil, nombre, ingreso) 
Tarjetas(cuil, tipo, limite)
adicionales(cuil_titutlar, cuil_adicional)

Como hago para obtener la cantidad de adicionales para cada titular.

GRACIAS.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 2):

Debes usar agrupado en combinación con función de agregado `count()`

```
select cuil_titutlar, count(cuil_titutlar)as 'Cantidad de adicionales'
from adicionales group by cuil_titutlar
```

Esto te va a devolver cada `cuil_titutlar` que esté en la tabla `adicionales` con la cantidad de veces que aparece. Si queres que muestre el nombre del titular debes unir las tablas, pero para que te lo resuelva de esta forma debes ampliar más información de la estructura de tus tablas